# auto-insert mode switch to new file

Tags: find-file, selection, auto-insert

I managed to insert a template to certain sripts with autocomplete.

Example:

```
(auto-insert-mode)
(setq auto-insert-query nil)
(setq auto-insert-alist
  '(((ess-mode . "R script") nil
     "# R script " \n
     "# file: " (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name) "\n"
       "# Description: " _ "\n\n")))
```

However, when creating a new file, the buffer-tab is now not selected as with "visit new file". Meaning, that the selected buffer remains selected. 
Can this behaviour be altered?

Admittedly, it is a minor problem, yet annyoing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but now it works as expected. Must have been some error before. This is the working version:

```
(auto-insert-mode)
(setq auto-insert-query nil)
(setq auto-insert-alist
      '(((ess-mode . "R script") nil
         "# R script " \n
         "# File: " (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name) "\n"
         "# Author: me " \n
         "# Contact: my@email.mail" \n
         "# Date: " (format-time-string "%e.%m.%Y") "\n"
         "# Copyright (C) " (substring (current-time-string) -4) "\n"
         "# Description: "  "\n\n")))
```